# Add to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function I can't modify:

```
function addToMe() { doStuff(); }
```

Can I add to this function? *Obviously this syntax is terribly wrong but it's the general idea...*

```
function addToMe() { addToMe() + doOtherStuff(); }
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could store a reference to the original function, and then override it, with a function that calls back the original one, and adds the functionality you desire:

```
var originalFn = addToMe;

addToMe = function () {
  originalFn(); // call the original function
  // other stuff
};
```

You can do this because JavaScript [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Functions) are [first-class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) objects.

**Edit:** If your function receives arguments, you should use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass them to the *original function*:

```
addToMe = function () {
  originalFn.apply(this, arguments); // preserve the arguments
  // other stuff
};
```

You could also use an auto-executing function expression with an argument to store the reference of the original function, I think it is a little bit cleaner:

```
addToMe = (function (originalFn) {
  return function () {
    originalFn.apply(originalFn, arguments); // call the original function
    // other stuff
  };
})(addToMe); // pass the reference of the original function
```

Comment: yep that's probably the simplest solution!

Comment: You should add a second return-statement before originalFn!