# How to prevent default in a function if a function already return somethiing

Tags: javascript

```
for(var i=0; i < 2; i++){
     someNode.onclick = function(num){
         return function(){
           alert(num);   
       }
    }(i)
}
```

This is my javascript,

```
<a href="http://example.com/"></a>
```

This is my node in html

I need to embed a function inside function due to closure issue, so how can I prevent the link from redirecting me to other page when I click the link? As it already return a function. It is impossible to me to add a `return false;`

Comment: `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: The nested function seems redundant

Comment: You're missing that the function which returns a function is not the onclick handler; the returned function is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `return false;`:

```
for(var i=0; i < 2; i++){
     someNode.onclick = function(num){
         return function(){
           alert(num);
           return false;   
       }
    }(i);
}
```

Or you could use `e.preventDefault` either:

```
for(var i=0; i < 2; i++){
     someNode.onclick = function(num){
         return function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           alert(num);   
       }
    }(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way : (Inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659219/add-to-a-javascript-function).)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ley7E/)**

```
// Your Existing code
for(var i=1; i <= 2; i++){
     document.getElementById("link"+ i).onclick = function(num){
         return function(){
           alert(num);   
       }
    }(i);
}


// Update the onclick event handlers to return false at end.
for(var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
    var node = document.getElementById("link"+ i);    
    node.onclick = (function (fn) {
      return function () { 
          fn.apply(fn, arguments);
          return false;
      };
    })(node.onclick);
}
```